# Invariant vector field of first integral

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I have to show that If $f:\delta\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a first integral of $X$ a vector field then $M_{c}=f^{-1}(c)$ is invariant by $X$
I tried diferenciating a solution $\phi$  at an orbit and also looking at $M_{c}$ as a union of orbits
Edit: i don't know If It helps but the orbit $\phi_{t}(m)$ where $m \in M$ is restricted to $\delta$ therefore $X(\phi_{t}(m) \in \delta$

Edit2: the previous is wrong, aparently the way is looking at the tangent plane of an orbit over a Surface defined by $X$, but i'm strugling with what Surface is that, i also think my definition of invariant is not good

Comment: What is $\delta$?  Cheers!

Comment: @RobertLewis its an open set of $\mathbb{R^n}$, the Domain of $X$

Comment: I figured it was something like that.  Thanks.

Comment: $f^{-1}(c)$ is simply invariant since $f$ is a first integral?

Comment: @T'x actually yes, im almost finishing It, If i do so before anyone answers ill post It here

Comment: Well yes, I mean there is nothing to proof there?

Comment: @T'x It's nothing to prove if you are allowed to use that. But the question seems to be how to prove this statement in the first place.

Comment: It comes right from definition, the thing the transformation you look at, the gradient of f times the vector field is null, therefore It Will be invariant, but i Want to improve the argument

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently $M_c$ is invariant by $X$ If It is tangent to the field
That translates to
$df(\phi_{t}(d))* X(d)=0$ for every $d\in M_{c}$
But this comes from definition.
QED